# How to open up a GNUPLOT file?

Tags: 16.04, gnuplot

I've outputted a gnuplot file called `out.data` as a plain text file. I have downloaded and install gnuplot but I can't seem to figure out how to open it.

```
gnuplot > plot out.data
```

But it gives me an error `undefined variable: out`

I have tried the following commands without success:

```
plot 'out.data'
plot 'out.data.txt'
plot out.data.txt
plot'home\peteuser\out.data.txt'
plot home\peteuser\out.data.txt
plot 'home\peteuser\out.data'
```

How can I open a gnuplot file?

Answer (score 1):

If your file is actually a plot script (not just the data), then use:

```
load "out.data"
```

if it's just the data then it will be

```
plot "out.data"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `plot "out.data" title ""`. More on `gnuplot` here: https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~vrable/gnuplot/using-gnuplot.html